# Python multithreading with System.Windows.Forms

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-multithreading

I'm pre-beginner in Python and English.
My question is I have a form with a button, when I click this button I expect some functionality to be done in another Thread. How can I do this?

How do I know when the Thread(`st`) will be completed?

```
def showForm():
   window = Form()
   window.Text = "example"
   window.Size = Size(500, 300)
   window.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.FixedDialog

   LOAD_BUTTON = Button()
   LOAD_BUTTON.Text = "Load"
   LOAD_BUTTON.Dock = DockStyle.Right
   LOAD_BUTTON.Click += show
   window.Controls.Add(LOAD_BUTTON)
   Application.Run(window)



def show(sender,e):
   st = threading.Thread(target=show_loop)
   st.start()


def show_loop():
   for i in range(0, 5):
       time.sleep(i)
       print i


sv = threading.Thread(target=showForm)
sv.start()
```

P.S
I have already read about Qt, tkinter and etc.

Comment: You can call [`Thread.is_alive()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#threading.Thread.is_alive) to see whether a thread is still running.

Comment: Yes, but after st.join()

Comment: No, you can call `is_alive()` without `join()`.

Comment: Yes, if i call is_alive() it will be print - true
`st.start()
st.is_alive()`